# Apache WebDAV to Accept POST as a PUT on New Resource

Tags: rest, apache2, webdav, apache2.4

I have a service that is POSTing to an Apache WebDAV endpoint [but POST is not a standard implemented method and on WebDAV](http://www.webdav.org/specs/rfc4918.html#METHOD_POST).

The end goal is to have files uploaded via a POST to create/overwrite a resource the exact same way a PUT method currently works; as when the service does a PUT, the file is successfully created, but on POST, it only works if a file already exists.

E.g:
Successful PUT on new resource

```
➜  ~ curl -X PUT -k  -F 'data=@test_file_upload.txt https://endpoint.tld/put_test.txt
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>201 Created</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Created</h1>
<p>Resource /put_test.txt has been created.</p>
</body></html>
```

Unsuccessful POST on new resource

```
➜  ~ curl -X POST -k  -F 'data=@test_file_upload.txt' https://endpoint.tld/post_test.txt
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /post_test.txt was not found on this server.</p>
</body></html>
```

I have tried Apache `Rewrite` but cannot change the method.

I am currently attempting to implement a Python3 Flask script with WSGI and a proxy request on POST; but this is becoming incredibly cumbersome and complicated.

Would using `mod_perl` allow me to script something without extending to a proxied request?

How can I leverage the lowest friction solution to have this working?

Comment: Actually it *is* standardized in RFC 5995 (as extension).

That said: why don't you use PUT? Can you explain why you can't?

Comment: @JulianReschke it's an upstream requirement that can't be changed unfortunately. It does PUT in during testing (which is perfect for Apache WebDAV) and then it changes to POST during prod. The request is unchanged other than POST method.