# Flask Upload with no Content-Type or Form Data at All

Tags: python-3.x, flask, stream

I'm attempting to get around [this WebDAV POST issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64328955/apache-webdav-to-accept-post-as-a-put-on-new-resource) with Python3 Flask using WSGI on Apache2.4 by proxying all POST requests to a script.

I've been able to successfully upload PUT to create a file using CURL which looks like this:
[image]

But when I trigger the intended service to upload, the PUT is missing `Content-Type` and form data:

[image]

This fails all Flask upload examples which contain a conditional for `request.files`:

```
@app.route('/<path:fullpath>', methods = ['POST', 'PUT'])
def upload_files(fullpath):
    if not request.files:
        abort(400, "File not found")
```

Despite my searching I have no idea how to proceed with such an upload (raw?) type.
I believe I need to work with streams, but even those examples work off `request.files()`.

Does anyone recognize how I might be able to upload these files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to use file streaming. After many days of searching I finally [found this blog post](https://izmailoff.github.io/web/flask-file-streaming/) which mentions the specific problem of using the Flask/Requests `file` call:

> The trick seems to be that you shouldn’t use other request attributes like request.form or request.file because this will materialize the stream into memory/file. Flask by default saves files to disk if they exceed 500Kb, so don’t touch file.

Running the attached method immediately solved the issue of upload without multipart-form:

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)


# Upload file as stream to a file.
@app.route("/upload", methods=["POST"])
def upload():
    with open("/tmp/output_file", "bw") as f:
        chunk_size = 4096
        while True:
            chunk = request.stream.read(chunk_size)
            if len(chunk) == 0:
                return
            f.write(chunk)
    return 'created', 201
```

(Full credit to @izmailoff, but I added the final line or else there would be a timeout issue on the receivers side)